# Changing a String into an int

Tags: java, file, parsing, methods

I have an array of string objects that was read from a file. Some of these strings I need to use as ints. I wrote a method to read the file but now I just don't know how to get the numbers from the file, here is the file

```
29,,
Chute,1,0
Chute,2,0
Chute,3,0
Chute,4,0
Chute,5,0
Chute,6,0
Chute,7,0
Chute,8,0
Chute,9,0
Chute,0,1
Chute,0,2
Chute,0,3
Chute,9,1
Chute,9,2
Chute,9,3
Ladder,0,5
Ladder,1,5
Ladder,2,5
Ladder,3,5
Ladder,4,5
Ladder,5,5
Ladder,6,5
Ladder,7,5
Ladder,8,5
Ladder,9,5
Ladder,9,6
```

here is my method

```
public void readBoard(String file)throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File clboard = new File ("myBoard.csv");
    Scanner x = new Scanner(clboard);
    while(x.hasNext())
    {
        String c = x.nextLine();
        String [] myboard =c.split(","); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a dedicated CSV library, e.g. [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), to read the file - the `split` method has a few oddities when used to handle CSV files, for example it misbehaves if the last element is blank.  To convert a string to an int, use `Integer.parseInt(str)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int numOne = Integer.parseInt(myboard[1]);
int numTwo = Integer.parseInt(myboard[2]);
```

immediately after your `split` line.

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] myboard = c.split(",");
if (myboard.length < 3) {
    // error message
} else {
    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(myboard[1]);
    int i2 = Integer.parseInt(myboard[2]);
}
```

You might also want to add a try/catch to handle `NumberFormatException` (which occurs when you try to convert something that isn't a number).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void readBoard(String file)throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File clboard = new File ("myBoard.csv");
    Scanner x = new Scanner(clboard);
    while(x.hasNext())    {
        List<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String c = x.nextLine();
        String [] myboard =c.split(",");
        for (String candid8 : myboard) {
           try {
                number.add(Integer.parseInt(candid8));
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Your numbers will now be in the number object, which is a List. If it's a more complex grammar, look into [jflex](http://jflex.de), as that seems to be the recommendation of Google.